# UX Research on professional services using chat support

Tags: chat, customer-support

are there studies available that can proof (or discredit) the fact that serving a professional service to a customer using a chat backed by specialized human operators is better than a self-service web interface especially for customers aged between 50 and 70?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a lot of studies on this subject. All the studies I know confirm your hypothesis (live is better), which is kind of obvious. In psychology, a need for help adds stress to an already existing cognitive load (the need to know something), which in turn makes things more difficult. If you're still stuck, there are two options: **You blame yourself for not being intelligent enough to understand the system**, or you **blame the system and leave.**

It's more helpful if you've someone to guide you through the process. And when things don't work, the user can blame the operator.

While you can argue that you can get things done faster instead of waiting for help (which I personally prefer), the reality is that most users prefer a human to assist them.

## Sources

- [**New research Reveals 75 percent of Customers Still Favor Live Agent Support for Customer Service vs 25 Percent Self-Service and Chatbot**s](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20181206005294/en/New-research-Reveals-75-percent-of-Customers-Still-Favor-Live-Agent-Support-for-Customer-Service-vs-25-Percent-Self-Service-and-Chatbots)
- [**Examining satisfaction with the experience during a live chat service encounter- implications for website providers**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318990296_Examining_satisfaction_with_the_experience_during_a_live_chat_service_encounter-_implications_for_website_providers)